# 2023 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

Joomla's [4th moderator election](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close. Since there were not enough candidates for a competitive election, we simply appointed the candidates who nominated themselves:

[image: Terry Carter]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Comment: Thanks for volunteering Terry!